# I used ssl on my site and it destroyed it .... If anyone know how to fix problem

Tags: wordpress, ssl

My site was working before ssl and it was looking like this...
https://ibb.co/GxWFJdK

and this was after...

https://ibb.co/mzVrWWP

I removed ssl and put site back on http and still it is not working it is broken...It is wordpress site

Comment: The sites provides practically no useful information to help in finding the problem, i.e. the only problem description is basically "its broken and worked before". Specifically it is unknown what you actually did __in detail__, what the configuration of the site was and is, what the URL of the site is, what the contents of any developed console is ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the console, might be some JS or CSS code is still serving from the `https://`, you need to save the permalinks settings from the backend to reset it to `http://`